# React: Export function to use in another component

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, google-places-api, google-places-autocomplete

I'm building out a Google Map on my Gatsby site with a search box that will allow users to search for their location. I've got a `Hero` component and a `Map` component, and all of the functionality is built into the `Map` component; the Google Maps API, autocomplete, Google Places etc. Here's what it looks like right now:

**Map.tsx**

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useCallback } from 'react';
import { GoogleMap, useLoadScript, Marker, InfoWindow } from '@react-google-maps/api';
import * as dealersData from 'assets/data/dealers.json';

import { Button } from 'components/button/Button';

import MapMarker from 'assets/images/icons/map-marker.png';
import SearchIcon from 'assets/svg/search.svg';

import usePlacesAutocomplete, { getGeocode, getLatLng } from 'use-places-autocomplete';

import {
  Combobox,
  ComboboxInput,
  ComboboxPopover,
  ComboboxList,
  ComboboxOption,
} from '@reach/combobox';
import '@reach/combobox/styles.css';

import s from './Map.scss';
import MapStyles from './_MapStyles';

const libraries = ['places'];

const mapContainerStyle = {
  width: '100%',
  height: '100%',
};

const options = {
  styles: MapStyles,
  disableDefaultUI: true,
  zoomControl: true,
};

interface MapProps {
  location: any;
  fetchedData: ReactNode;
}

export const Map = ({ location, fetchedData }: MapProps) => {

  const center = {
    lat: location.location.latitude,
    lng: location.location.longitude,
  };

  const [selectedDealer, setselectedDealer] = useState(null);

  const { isLoaded, loadError } = useLoadScript({
    googleMapsApiKey: process.env.GATSBY_GOOGLE_MAPS_API,
    libraries,
  });

  const mapRef = useRef();
  const onMapLoad = useCallback((map) => {
    mapRef.current = map;
  }, []);

  const panTo = useCallback(({ lat, lng }) => {
    mapRef.current.panTo({ lat, lng });
    mapRef.current.setZoom(10);
  }, []);

  if (loadError) return <div className={s.map}>Error loading maps...</div>;
  if (!isLoaded) return <div className={s.map}>Loading...</div>;

  return (
    <>
      <div className={s.map}>
        <div className={s.map__search}>
          <Search panTo={panTo}></Search>
        </div>

        <GoogleMap
          mapContainerStyle={mapContainerStyle}
          zoom={10}
          center={center}
          options={options}
          onLoad={onMapLoad}
        >
          {dealersData.features.map((dealer) => (
            <Marker
              key={dealer.properties.DEALER_ID}
              position={{
                lat: dealer.geometry.coordinates[1],
                lng: dealer.geometry.coordinates[0],
              }}
              onClick={() => {
                setselectedDealer(dealer);
              }}
              icon={{
                url: MapMarker,
                scaledSize: new window.google.maps.Size(30, 30),
              }}
            />
          ))}

          {selectedDealer && (
            <InfoWindow
              position={{
                lat: selectedDealer.geometry.coordinates[1],
                lng: selectedDealer.geometry.coordinates[0],
              }}
              onCloseClick={() => {
                setselectedDealer(null);
              }}
            >
              <div className={s.dealer}>
                <h2 className={s.dealer__name}>
                  {selectedDealer.properties.NAME}
                  <span className={s.phone}>{selectedDealer.properties.PHONE_NUMBER}</span>
                </h2>
                <div className={s.dealer__info}>
                  <p className={s.address}>{selectedDealer.properties.ADDRESS}</p>
                  <p className={s.address}>
                    {selectedDealer.properties.CITY}, {selectedDealer.properties.STATE}{' '}
                    {selectedDealer.properties.ZIP_CODE}
                  </p>
                </div>
                <Button>Set Location</Button>
              </div>
            </InfoWindow>
          )}
        </GoogleMap>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export function Search({ panTo }) {
  const {
    ready,
    value,
    suggestions: { status, data },
    setValue,
    clearSuggestions,
  } = usePlacesAutocomplete({
    requestOptions: {
      location: { lat: () => 38.8299359, lng: () => -121.3070356 },
      radius: 200 * 1000,
    },
  });

  return (
    <>
      <div className={s.search__input}>
        <i className={s.search__icon}>
          <SearchIcon />
        </i>
        <Combobox
          onSelect={async (address) => {
            setValue(address, false);
            clearSuggestions();

            try {
              const results = await getGeocode({ address });
              const { lat, lng } = await getLatLng(results[0]);
              panTo({ lat, lng });
            } catch (error) {
              console.log('error');
            }
          }}
        >
          <ComboboxInput
            value={value}
            onChange={(e: any) => {
              setValue(e.target.value);
            }}
            disabled={!ready}
            placeholder="Enter your location"
          />
          <ComboboxPopover>
            <ComboboxList>
              {status === 'OK' &&
                data.map(({ id, description }) => <ComboboxOption key={id} value={description} />)}
            </ComboboxList>
          </ComboboxPopover>
        </Combobox>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

And here's my Hero component:

**Hero.tsx**

```
import React from 'react';

import s from './Hero.scss';

import { RichText } from 'prismic-reactjs';

import { linkResolver } from 'utils/linkResolver';
import htmlSerializer from 'utils/htmlSerializer';

import { Search } from '../map/_Map';

export const Hero = ({ content, panTo }: any) => (
  <div className={s.hero} data-theme={content.theme}>
    <div className={s.hero__container}>
      <div className={s.content}>
        <h1 className={s.content__heading}>{RichText.asText(content.page_title)}</h1>
        <div className={s.content__copy}>
          {RichText.render(content.copy, linkResolver, htmlSerializer)}
        </div>
        <Search panTo={panTo}></Search>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

Essentially, I'm needing to utilize the `Search` function in my `Hero` component, but when I export it and import it into the `Hero` its rendering just fine, but it never loads the `use-places-autocomplete` library, and won't work. What am I doing wrong? Is there any way to export the search function to reuse?

I've created an SSCCE, as asked in the comments here. The search function works if I utilize it directly in the Map component, but if it's imported into the hero, it doesn't load.

https://codesandbox.io/s/dawn-glitter-zi7lx

Thanks.

Comment: Are there any errors of in the console?

Comment: Please show us your Hero component.

Comment: @dhruvtailor there aren't.

Comment: @k-wasilewski updated my question.

Comment: did you ever add `export` in front of your search declaration? ```function Search(...)``` I don't see how it would work how you have it

Comment: I did, yes. Updated accordingly.

Comment: if you're not getting any errors, I would think the `usePlacesAutocomplete` is being imported, otherwise 

```const {
    ready,
    value,
    suggestions: { status, data },
    setValue,
    clearSuggestions,
  } = usePlacesAutocomplete({
    requestOptions: {
      location: { lat: () => 38.8299359, lng: () => -121.3070356 },
      radius: 200 * 1000,
    },
  });```

would fail with an error.

Comment: Can you provide an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) of your code?

Comment: @Pagemag updated my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for providing the sscce of your code in codesandbox. It looks like you are loading the Google Maps Javascript script tag only inside the `<Map/>` and not inside `<Hero/>`. You can see in your console log that there is a message to load the library.

To make it work, I used [**LoadScript**](https://react-google-maps-api-docs.netlify.app/#loadscript) of @react-google-maps/api in your **index.tsx** and put both  and  components in order for both script to work. Here's a sample of the index.tsx.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { LoadScript } from "@react-google-maps/api";

import { Map } from "./Map";
import { Hero } from "./Hero";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");

const App = () => {
  return (
    <React.StrictMode>
      <LoadScript
        googleMapsApiKey="YOUR_API_KEY"
        libraries={["places"]}
      >
        <Hero />
        <Map />
      </LoadScript>
    </React.StrictMode>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

I also removed **useLoadScript** in Map.tsx to make sure that it won't have conflict with the script loaded in the index.tsx.

Comment: So, if you notice, there's a part of the `Search` function, called `panTo` that actually makes the map change what it's showing based on the location that you choose. That isn't working on this change, although the input itself works now! Any ideas on how to get that up and running?

Comment: This is because your `panTo` is only defined inside <Map/> in the Map.tsx. That's why the `panTo({ lat, lng });` inside your <Search/> in the Hero.tsx proceed to the try catch error. You need to find a way to pass the {lat lng} of your <Search/> in Hero.tsx to use it in a function that pans the map object to that coordinate.